# node modules not found in vs code editor

Tags: node-modules

I have a standard fresh Nextjs project with typescript but somehow I get a compiler warning.
[image]

I have to add "../node_modules" extension while the node modules are in my root folder. Anyone knows how to fix this error? During a npm run dev I'm not getting any errors its just this red cringly error thats annoying me.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

"moduleResolution":"node" had to be added to the compileroptions in tsconfig.json